# Access current item when clicking link in dom-if inside dom-repeat

Tags: polymer

I have the following template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myItems}}">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{_shouldHaveLink(item)}}">
    <a href="#" on-tap="_linkTapped">Link</a>
  </template>
</template>
```

Now, if the link was not wrapped in a `dom-if`, I can see the item which was pressed with:

```
  _linkTapped: function (oEvent) {
    console.log('Item link tapped:', oEvent.model.get('item'));
  }
```

But inside the `dom-if` I can't. Seems like `item` is now out of scope. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2574) with Polymer's `dom-repeat` yet to be solved, but there's a simple workaround in this scenario.

Since the [`dom-if`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-if) template without [`restamp`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-if#property-restamp) simply hides its contents when the `if` condition is `false` (as an optimization), you could simulate the original behavior while avoiding the `dom-if`-related bug by replacing the template with a `hidden` attribute based on the same condition negated:

```
<div hidden$="{{!_shouldHaveLink(item)}}">
  <a href="#" on-tap="_linkTapped">Link</a>
</div>
```

or:

```
<a href="#" hidden$="{{!_shouldHaveLink(item)}}" on-tap="_linkTapped">Link</a>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [
          { name: 'google', link: 'http://www.google.com' },
          { name: 'facebook' },
          { name: 'twitter', link: 'http://www.twitter.com' },
        ]
      }
    },
    _hasNoLink: function(item) {
      return !item.link;
    },
    _linkTapped: function(e) {
      console.log(e.model.item);
      // for demo only...
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>Facebook anchor is hidden because it has no link</div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <a href="#"
           hidden$="{{_hasNoLink(item)}}"
           on-tap="_linkTapped">[[item.name]]</a>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qqdWrj?editors=1010)

And as @DocDude suggested, another alternative is to use [`<dom-repeat>.modelForElement(e.target)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat#method-modelForElement) if you have a reference to the `<dom-repeat>`:

```
//template
<template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">

// script
_linkTapped: function(e) {
  const m = this.$.repeater.modelForElement(e.target);
  console.log(m.item);
  ...
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [
          { name: 'google', link: 'http://www.google.com' },
          { name: 'facebook' },
          { name: 'twitter', link: 'http://www.twitter.com' },
        ]
      }
    },
    _hasLink: function(item) {
      return item.link;
    },
    _linkTapped: function(e) {
      const m = this.$.repeater.modelForElement(e.target);
      console.log(m.item);

      // for demo only...
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.3.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>Facebook anchor is hidden because it has no link</div>
      <template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{_hasLink(item)}}">
          <a href="#" on-tap="_linkTapped">[[item.name]]</a>
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MbwYwq?editors=1011)

Comment: This is a good answer. You should also be able to retrieve the `model` object if you have a reference to the `dom-repeat` (for example, `this.$.repeater`):  `var m = this.$.repeater.modelForElement(e.target);` Then  you can reference `m.item` (or `m.get('item')` I think they're the same thing in this case.)

Comment: Precise and comprehensive answer, including workarounds! Thank you both!